# Numbering equation includes array

Tags: latex

I'm trying to numbering the equations but since I'm using `\begin{array}`, `\begin{equation}` and `\begin{align}` are not working. What can I use to number this equation?

```
   \begin{equation}
    \[ \ F (t;\theta) = \left\{ \begin{array}{cl}
    1- e^{-\theta t}=1-e^{-\frac{t}{{}t_{x}}} & \ ; \ if \ t \geq 0 \\
     0  & \ ; \ if \ t \leq 0 \end{array} \right. \]
  \end{equation}
```

Comment: Dear reviewers, this is a pure tex problem and unrelated to programming. I think it would be best if it would be migrated to tex.stackexchange.com

Comment: @ Ozicek Please note that `\begin{equation}` already switches to math mode. It is not necessary to use `\[..\]` inside of the `equation` environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of reinventing the wheel, use the `cases` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cases}
\begin{document}

\begin{numcases}{F(t;\theta)=}
   1- e^{-\theta t}=1-e^{-\frac{t}{{}t_{x}}}  & if $t \geq 0$
   \\
   0 & if $t\leq 0$ 
\end{numcases}

\end{document}
```

[image]